# ASP.NET MVC can't read cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

This ought to be simple enough, although I find I can only set cookies but not read them back, despite my browser showing me the cookie.

In my `HomeController` I set the cookie once a user enters a valid string:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string fMemberCode)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: controller-->member table module-->member data gateway-->DB
        // Check member num against member table
        //  Return cookie if exists
        //  Return error if not
        MembersModule membersModule = new MembersModule();
        int memberId = membersModule.AuthMember(fMemberCode);
        if (memberId > 0)
        {
            HttpCookie mCookie = new HttpCookie("MMedia");
            mCookie.Value = memberId.ToString();
            Response.Cookies.Add(mCookie);
        }
        else { }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then later on, in a different context, the `LibraryController` needs to check the cookie is present:

```
public LibraryController()
{
    // TODO
    // Check member cookie present
    int id = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["Media"].Value);
    if (id > 0)
        this.module = new LibraryModule(id);
    else throw new Exception("Invalid cookie");
}
```

However, when stepping through the code in VS2012 when the line of execution in `LibraryController` reaches:

```
int id = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["Media"].Value);
```

The exception is thrown: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Is `MMedia` a typo when you go to create it? (vs. `Media` when you recall it)

Comment: I changed the name to be more appropriate. The problem still remains though.

Comment: And you've confirmed the cookie's returned to the user, and the user is issuing the cookie back on future requests? (You say browser is showing you the cookie, but didn't know if `path` or `domain` may be playing a part.)

Comment: Yes the cookie is created fine it seems. I tested further by returning all cookies to an `HttpCookieCollection` and the same exception was thrown. It's acting as though there are no cookie objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access the `Request` property in the constructor of your controller. It doesn't exist at that point in the controller life cycle.

Perhaps an action or controller filter might help you.

Comment: touché. Probably it, didn't catch on that it was being referenced in the ctor.

Comment: Excellent observation. I forgot I was working in the constructor! I placed it in the LibraryController Index action instead.